# How to retrieve private photoalbums with the Picasa API

Tags: php, google-api, picasa

I have my oAuth authorization with Picasa working and I can fetch all the albums using access=all, however when I change my access to 'private' in the following URL I'd expect to get my private albums. I get all my hangout albums (with limited visibility) instead.

https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/default?kind=album&access={access}

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/2.0/reference#Visibility) there are 3 possible values. 'All' returns everything and 'public' returns only my public albums (as expected). But I was wondering if the switch to Google+ Photos perhaps included another parameter that was not mentioned in the Picasa API documentation?

Also would it be possible to retrieve my public and private albums, but not my hangout albums?

Comment: I don't understand. The documentation you linked lists 4 possible values: `all`, `public`, `private`, and `visible`. Is there a difference between `private` and `hangout` albums?

Comment: Well, hangout albums have 'special' permissions (according to G+) and are only shared with the persons in that hangout. Since they are not public, it's fine with me they are considered private. The thing is that all other albums that are strict private or shared with a link don't appear when I request private albums. Those are the ones I'm most interested in.

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you're looking for [Google Picasa Web Api: Get the private album](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714201/google-picasa-web-api-get-the-private-album) 
From what it seems you only need to give it an &access_token={access token} while using oAuth and it should return the photos you want private or not.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, that other question is about using ZEND (I communicate directly with the API). And as far as I can tell I am fully authorised already. But I'll give it a go when I get home :)